# R - paste() invokes as.numeric() when passing data frame to it?

Tags: string, r, numeric, paste

I have a particular problem with **Rs `paste`-function in combination with the row- and coloumn-selection of a data frame**. It seems that **`paste` always surrounds it's input-arguments with `as.numeric()`** or something which does a similar job.

Here is a code snippet of what I am doing:

```
paste(df[1, c("entry1", "entry2")], collapse="; ")
```

This passes the first row of a data frame `df` with column entries for column `"entry1"` and `"entry2"`. I assumed an output like this:

```
"Auffuellung; Holozaen"
```

Instead I am receiving the concatenated number equivalents (not indices) of the passed data frame entries:

```
"1; 5"
```

Calling `str(df[1, c("entry1", "entry2")])` on my real data base results in the following output (German, do not wonder ;) ):

```
'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Hauptbestandteile: Factor w/ 38 levels "Auffuellung",..: 1
 $ Chronografie     : Factor w/ 18 levels "Devon","Famennium",..: 5
```

What am I doing wrong in this case? Until now, I never faced such a problem with the `paste`-function and I would have never expected something like this to happen. **So, how do I solve the problem and get the correct output of concatenated strings instead of concatenated number equivalents?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry, that I didn't described it ealier. It is the first row of a data frame, containing 2 column entries.

Comment: @SimonO101 I added the `str`-output the the question-post.

Comment: @SimonO101 , my expected output is "Auffuellung; Holozaen" after the `paste`. Maybe the solution is to somehow extract the string values which are hidden behind the dataframe-internal, somehow sorted enumeration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is related to the fact that your data are `factor` variables. `paste` is pasting the underlying `"integer"` code. This is confusing and not immediately obvious as to how to get around it. You need to turn it into a vector using `unlist()` and it will work as exepcted...

#### Example

```
df <- data.frame( Month = factor(month.name) , Short = factor(month.abb) )
df[ 1 , ]
#    Month Short
#1 January   Jan

paste( df[ 1 , ] , collapse = "; " )
#[1] "5; 5"

paste( unlist( df[ 1 , ] ) , collapse = "; " )
#[1] "January; Jan"
```

Of course when reading your data in you can avoid strings being automatically converted to factors using the `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` argument to `read.*`.

See the [**R room chat log here**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/12827440#12827440) for a discussion on this.

Comment: I just found out that there is a `stringsAsFactors`-argument in the `read.csv`-function. It is set to `stringsAsFactors=default.stringsAsFactors()` as default. In my case it hase to be `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`. This absolutely solves any issues. Please add this to your answer and I will accept it as the right one.